# Stored procedure for altering data after transferring it from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have Table A, with one column "destination", and Table B, with a column called "location". I want to create a stored procedure that inserts the data in "destination" from A into "location" from B. Let's say the data in "destination" is an integer--let's make its value "123" for this scenario-- and after it is inserted into Table B, I want the procedure to affix a "4" to the end of it, making the value "1234". How do I go about doing this?

Below is what I have for the stored procedure so far, before adding the edits that need to be made to alter the integer values being transferred:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'stored_procedure' (IN p_destination int)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO table_b(location)

SELECT destination

FROM table_a

WHERE destination = p_destination;

"code here for adding "4" to the end of value"

END
```

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :** Assuming that location in table B is also integer column

```
INSERT INTO table_b(location)
SELECT CAST(CAST(destination AS VARCHAR(30))+'4' AS INT)
FROM table_a
WHERE destination = p_destination;
```

OR you can right UPDATE command after inserting Data into Table B

```
UPDATE Table_b
SET destination = CAST(CAST(destination AS VARCHAR(30))+'4' AS INT)
```

This will Updates all rows from Table_b

Comment: Tried it, but this just results in simple addition, where "123" becomes "127" instead of "1234". Do I need to convert "destination" into a different data type?

Comment: Have you tried exact script means first we convert destination to varchar then append string 4 and then again convert that resultant string into Integer

Answer (score 0):

Use this insert query in your procedure

`insert into table_b(location) select destination+'4' from table_a WHERE destination = p_destination`